# How to read an input file that occasionally contains extra line feeds?

Tags: bash, text-processing

Most of the time, I am given an input file that looks like this:

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64  1:1.8.0.232.b09-1.el6_10        asyum:ol6_latest
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:1.8.0.232.b09-1.el6_10        asyum:ol6_latest
kernel.x86_64              2.6.32-754.23.1.el6             asyum:ol6_latest
```

...and I have a while loop that is able to successfully capture field1 and field2 from each line using this code:

```
f1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
f2=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
```

However, I'll occasionally get input files that look similar to this:

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64  1:1.8.0.232.b09-1.el6_10        asyum:ol6_latest
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64
                           1:1.8.0.232.b09-1.el6_10        asyum:ol6_latest
kernel.x86_64              2.6.32-754.23.1.el6             asyum:ol6_latest
```

(Notice there is an extra line feed that splits line 2.)

Do you have any tips/tricks for handling this type of input programmatically (instead of manually cleaning up the input file)?

Comment: Ah, my bad! I had the wrong understanding regarding what a CR is until I read your reply. I meant LF. (My input files do not contain any CRs.)

Comment: Actually, yes--leading spaces after the extra LF are always there. (Never realized this before.) Not sure if this matters, but sometimes the extra LF is after the SECOND field, like this:

Comment: line 1: java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64          1:1.7.0.241-2.6.20.0.0.1.el7_7

Comment: line 2:                                                             asyum:ol7_latest

Comment: (FYI, line 2 DOES have preceding spaces before "asyum"; I just can't get them to show up here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should achieve what's required:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read line; do
    declare -a array=($line)
    if  test ${#array[@]} != 3; then
        read line2
        array+=($line2)
    fi
    f1=${array[0]}
    f2=${array[1]}
    echo $f1 $f2
done

run with : test.sh < inputfile
```

It checks if a line contains three items, if not, join next line.

Comment: You set up an array beautifully but then you revert to awk to pick out field values from the line that are almost already in your array. What!?

Comment: In case the line is incomplete, the array does not contain everything.

Comment: thank you Philippe! This worked!

Comment: Instead of `line+=" $line2"` you put `array+=($line2)` and then you have `"${array[0]}"` as the first element and `"${array[1]}"` as the second.

Comment: You are right, updated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that relies solely on leading space(s). It doesn't rely on expected number of fields.

The [manual of GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Joining-lines.html) provides a way to "join lines that start with whitespace":

> ```
> sed -E ':a ; $!N ; s/\n\s+/ / ; ta ; P ; D'
> ```

The manual claims a portable (non-GNU) variation is:

> ```
> sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n  */ /;ta' -e 'P;D'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `awk` anyhow, why not rely on it entirely? Try

```
read f1 f2 <<< $(awk '{while (NF < 3) {getline X; $0 = $0 FS X};  print $1, $2}' file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xargs -n3 -a inputfile` to rearrange the input file and put three elements on each line.

```
while read -r f1 f2 temp; do
  echo "f1=$f1"
  echo "f2=$f2"
done < <(xargs -n3 -a inputfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that every well-formed line of your input data was made of three words (loosely defined here as strings not containing any blank character), you may preprocess your input data:

```bsh
<input_file tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' | paste - - - | column -t
```

Here, we are replacing any blank character (including `<newline>` characters) with a single `<newline>`, rearranging the result into lines of three words and nicely formatting the output—the last one being an unnecessary, cosmetic step, given your question.